# Google Sheets: How can I write a custom formula that counts the number of cells based on color?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have the following code that I found online, but I'm getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of null (line 6, file "Code")"

I want to be able to create a custom formula that I can then use like a regular formula which I can link and reference cells. Other versions of this code have cell references as a static hardcode, so I wanted to use this version. Any help is appreciated - I am new to this so I may be missing something really obvious.

```html
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Counting background colors of the active range**

```
function countBGColors() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var bA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var color={cA:[]};
  for(var i=0;i<bA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<bA[i].length;j++) {
      if(!color.hasOwnProperty(bA[i][j])) {
        color[bA[i][j]]=1;
        color.cA.push(bA[i][j]);
      }else{
        color[bA[i][j]]+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,50).setBackground('#ffffff');
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,50).setValue('');
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,color.cA.length).setBackgrounds([color.cA]);
  for(var i=0;i<color.cA.length;i++) {                                             
    sh.getRange(1,i+1).setValue(color[color.cA[i]])
  }
}
```

The script counts the colors and displays the color in the order that it encountered them.  It then places the colors in the upper right hand corner and places the number of each color in it's cell.

Animation:

[image]